# IE 7 and 8 SSL download from simple HTML page not working, tomcat server

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tomcat, ssl

I have a simple HTML file which has one link to a file kept for download. The site uses SSL (self signed cert). When I click on the file to be downloaded in FF or Chrome, it works fine and saves the file on to disk.

Here is the code-

```
<html><body> download from <a href="hello.tar.gz">here</a></body></html>
```

When I open the same page with IE 7/8, and click on the link, it gives an error saying "Internet Explorer cannot open hello.tar.gz from server"

Edit: Forgot to mention that IE 7 / 8 works fine without SSL.

Please help!
-Keshav

UPDATE: Solved the problem with a tomcat 6 configuration. Here is the link that helped me solve the problem-
http://community.eapps.com/showthread.php?p=461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE normally downloads attachments into its "Temporary Internet Files" folder, however when the site is in HTTPS mode the attachments will not be downloaded.

Theres detailed explanation in this article.

[IE and HTTPS for the whole site with a '/' as the url-pattern](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Adding+SSL+for+Secure+Logins+and+Page+Security)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I found another link http://community.eapps.com/showthread.php?p=461 related to this that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the MIME types for the file extension *.gz (or *.tar.gz)?

It sounds like IE is trying to interpret the file as gzipped HTML, instead of prompting to download it.

Comment: Hi ewall, it does not matter what the file is. It does not even work for a txt file.

Comment: Another couple things you could do to get more info: (1) turn off "Show friendly HTTP error messages" in the IE clients and (2) use a tool like the Firefox add-in "Live HTTP Headers" to view the requests and returned headers when the browser tries to retrieve the file.

Comment: Oh well the prompt for file save does come up. But it also errors out. Will try to post the image.